# How to call backend service by clicking on dropdown element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on CRUD operations. Their is an additional operation in Update that is "ModifyUsersinGroup"

I have a list of user.
I have groups.
Each group have many users
What I am doing right now in ModifyUserinGroup is I am able to get all assigned users in a group from back end service and I am able to add new users from dropdown.
I also have a dropdown which shows all the users.

Problem Statement:
By clicking on Users in dropdownlist, If a User already exists in a group then by clicking on that user, It should call same backend service check that if this user is already existing in a group then either hide it or disable it or display an error message on clicking it "Cannot to add user"
How can I do that.

```
Here is my code ->  https://jsfiddle.net/Jenfier/96xggc6s/
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jenfier/96xggc6s/)

Comment: that fiddle aint working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Jenfier/96xggc6s/  click on this URL

Answer (score 0):

Just like **ng-click=""** which triggers on the click, you can use **ng-change=""** to call a validating function that takes care of your requirement.

I presume you are using **select element**, if so, then here is an example

```
// Notice "userValidation()" specified under 
// ng-chage="", which will be triggered on selecting a value from dropdown.

<select class="form-control" id="selectUser" ng-model="user" ng-required="true" ng-options=" user.name as user.name for user in UserList" 
    ng-change="userValidation(user)">
</select>
```

And in the Controller, define your validation steps using **REST** call as per your requirement.

```
$scope.userValidation=function(user){

 // doSomething...
    *
    *
    *
 // doSomething...

};
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: I am using  multi drop down class where in model i am using Selected user which is reponsible for bringing all those users which are assigned to a group
<div class="form-group">

                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="create_group">Modify Users</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <multiselect-dropdown class="col-md-12" model=" SelectedUser " options="UserList "></multiselect-dropdown>
                        </div>